# I have a grouped UITableView and I need to make it look like a plain UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView, it's a grouped one. I need it to be grouped because I have different sections, different headers for each sections, etc, etc but I need to make it look like a plain table, make the cells fit the whole width of the screen, and remove the rounded corners...

I've been googling and stackoverflowing but I couldn't find any answer to this... the most close I got was to set the cells to:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

But that's not what I need, because the cells are now transparent but when I select one I can still see in the selection that the shape of the cell is rounded... also I can't change the color of the cell...

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make it plain style (`UITableViewStylePlain`). The style is related to the look of the table view, not whether it has sections / headers / footers or not.

If you created the table in an XIB file, change the style in the Utilities view, Table View section, Style.

If you're creating the table in code, change the style during `initWithStyle:`.

Comment: ok... but there is no action to change the style of a table... do I have to extend the table and make my own class?

Comment: You have to create the table view with the required style.